# How to set shell output to a variable in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to get a `shell` output to a variable in `set_fact` in `ansible`. And this variable is referred in the somewhere in the same `playbook` but targeting a different set of hosts

But I am not sure how to do that.

This is my `playbook`:

```
---
- hosts: kube-master
  tasks:
    - name: Print the value
      become: true
      shell: |
        echo "hi"
      set_fact:
        banuka: <value-taken-from-above-shell-command>

- hosts: kube-minions
  tasks:
    - name: Print the variable
      become: true
      shell: |
        echo {{banuka}}
```

But I don't know these:

**1. How to get the shell command output to the variable in `set_fact` and refer it somewhere**

**2. Is it possible to have multiple hosts (as shown in the above playbook)**

Answer (score 3):

I would do it the following way:

```
---
- hosts: master01
  tasks:
  - name: Print the value
    shell: |
      echo "hi"
    register: somevariablename
  - name: set fact
    set_fact:
      myvar: "{{ somevariablename.stdout }}"

- hosts: kube-minions
  tasks:
  - name: Print the variable
    shell: |
      echo "{{ hostvars['master01'].myvar }}"
```

It's important to understand, that `set_fact` only set a variable on the host which it's executed. Since you have a group `kube-master` it could be executed on each. I had the same issue in a playbook with Kubernetes-Masters and i used one of them as a "primary" e.q. `master01`. Then the `echo hi` will only be executed on that one.

In the second hostgroup, you must refer to the hostvars of your kube-master host like the master01.

Do you have the need to run over all the hosts in the group `kube-master`?

Comment: hosts `kube-master` has only one server and `kube-minions` 3 servers.

Comment: So what I want to do this, get the `join` token from master and execute in on the minions. So this way I think it will be possible, but the problem is, when i execute `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` it prints the with a `warning`. So how can I get rid of warning and only prints the `join` command itself?

Comment: You could experiment with filters:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters

 echo "{{ hostvars['master01'].myvar | regex_search('(foo)') }}"

Comment: Hi, I tried your above method, but it gives an error in `hostvars['master01'].myvar` line. I changed this line according to mine, but still it fails

Comment: hostvars['thismustbeyourhostname'] <-- this must contain your masters hostname, the name which you used in your inventory

Comment: yes, as you can see in my question, it is `kube-master` so I used that and still says that value is `undefined`